# Centripetal acceleration in Kepler orbit in cartesian coordinate

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, physics, conic-sections

I have some difficult in deriving the formula for centripetal acceleration of a planet in solar system moving in elliptical orbit with constant areal velocity $\dot S$.

The book report the formula in cartesian coordinate:

$$a_c=\frac{4\dot S^2(1+(\frac{cy}{b^2})^2)}{((x+c)^2+y^2)}\frac{a^4b}{(a^4+c^2x^2)^\frac 3 2}$$

With:
a = semi major axis
b = semi minor axis
$c = \sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ semi focal distance

I try using polar coordinate find $a_c$ and then return to cartesian but i get stuck.

I guess that the last part is the curvature and the first is $r^2\dot\theta$ but have no idea for the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the 
[ellipse with the associated polar coordinates, where the rightmost focus coincides with the origin and Sun.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqXFR.png)

In that figure, the Sun is at the origin and the origin is chosen to coincide with the right focal point of the ellipse. Now there is enough information to give a Cartesian description of the ellipse,
$$ \frac{(x+c)^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} =1 $$ 
where $(x,y)$ is the position of the planet at some instant in time. Use the formula (Stewart Calculus 7th edition, p891),
$$ \vec{a} = a_T \vec{T} + a_{N}\vec{N} = \frac{|\vec{v}(t)\times \vec{a}(t)|}{|\vec{v}(t)|}\vec{N} + \frac{|\vec{v}(t)\cdot \vec{a}(t)|}{|\vec{v}(t)|}\vec{T}$$ where $\vec{N}$ is a unit vector directed towards the center of curvature and hence normal to the velocity and $\vec{T}$ is a unit vector in the direction of velocity. The goal is to compute $a_N$.
To avoid polar coordinates and what not we use $a_N = \kappa v^2$ (Stewart Calculus p891 7th ed). From page 881 of Stewart Calculus 7th ed. the curvature,
$$ \kappa(x) = \frac{|f''(x)|}{(1+f'(x)^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$ which explains the power of $\frac{3}{2}$ you have. Theoretically speaking this approach is sketchy since $y$ is clearly not a function of $x$ whereas this formula works for functions only; however, there comes the beauty of symmetry, if we consider only the upper half of the ellipse, which is a graph of a function, the radius of curvature there, at any given abscissa $x$, will be the same for the lower half of the ellipse at the same abscissa.

Using implicit differentiation one gets,
$$ \frac{(x+c)}{a^2} + \frac{yy'}{b^2} = 0 \Rightarrow y' = -\frac{-b^2(x+c)}{ya^2}$$
Using implicit differentiation twice one gets,
$$ \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2}(y'^2+yy'')=0 \Rightarrow |y''| = \frac{\frac{b^2}{a^2}+y'^2}{y}=
 \frac{\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{b^4(x+c)^2}{y^2a^4}}{y} =\frac{b^4}{a^2 y^3}$$
Thus, $$ y'^2+1= y|y''|-\frac{b^2}{a^2} +1= \frac{b^4}{a^2y^2}-\frac{b^2}{a^2}+1=\frac{b^4-b^2y^2+a^2y^2}{a^2y^2}=\frac{c^2y^2+b^4}{a^2y^2}$$
Therefore, $$\displaystyle \kappa(x) = \frac{b^4a}{(b^4+c^2y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
Now, in polar coordinates $\vec{v} = \dot{\rho}\vec{e}_{\rho} + \rho\dot{\phi}\vec{e}_{\phi} \Rightarrow v^2 = \dot{\rho}^2 +(\rho\dot{\phi})^2 $.

The area swept between the angles $\phi_0$ and $\phi$ is $S(\phi) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\phi_0}^{\phi} (\rho(\phi))^2 d\phi$  hence $\dot{S} =\frac{1}{2} \rho^2 \dot{\phi}$ which is a constant due to conservation of angular momentum. From the figure I attached one sees that $\rho  + \rho' = 2a  =\rho + \sqrt{(\rho \sin{\phi})^2+(2c+\rho \cos{\phi})^2}$ hence $$\displaystyle \rho = \frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos{\phi}}$$ where $e=\frac{c}{a}$ is the eccentricity of the ellipse. Differentiating and using the formula obtained for $\dot{S}$ ,
$$ \dot{\rho} = \frac{2e\dot{S}}{a(1-e^2)}\sin{\phi}=\frac{2e\dot{S}}{\rho a(1-e^2)}\rho\sin{\phi}=\frac{2e\dot{S}} {a(1-e^2)}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
Now, to calculate $\rho \dot{\phi} = 2\frac{\dot{S}}{\rho}=2\frac{\dot{S}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Therefore, 
$$ v^2 = \dot{\rho}^2+(\rho\dot{\phi})^2 = \frac{4\dot{S}^2}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{4e^2\dot{S}^2}{a^2(1-e^2)^2}\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$
after some careful algebraic changes, 
$$ v^2 = \frac{4\dot{S}^2\left( 1+\left(\frac{cy}{b^2} \right)^2\right)}{x^2+y^2}$$
and finally $$a_c =\frac{4\dot{S}^2\left( 1+\left(\frac{cy}{b^2} \right)^2\right)}{x^2+y^2}\frac{b^4 a}{(b^4+c^2y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

Comment: I tried three other approaches but all of them were longer than this, but I do think this question is more geometrically relevant than physics-relevant so good choice!

Comment: thank you so much! I was struggling using the eccentric anomaly parametrization because maybe the areal velocity expression was simpler but your explanation is very good and clear. thank you.